# Insert only half a pdf page

Tags: pdf, pdfpages, include, thesis

I'd like to include papers of mine which can easily be done with the `pdfpages` packages:

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\includepdf[pages=-]{mypaper.pdf}
```

However, my thesis has an A5 format. Which means that each page is "half" an A4 page. Basically, I'd like two include each PDF page on two pages, like illustrated below:

[image]

While I found how to rotate the PDF using the `angle` parameter, I did not find how to split it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can insert the left/right half of the A4 page using [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry,lipsum,eso-pic}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\geometry{
  paper = a5paper
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}% Set something blank on page

% Add top part of A4 PDF
\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    % A4 = 2 x A5
    \includegraphics[angle = 90, height = \paperheight, valign = B]{example-image-a4}
  }%
}

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}% Set something blank on page

% Add bottom part of A4 PDF
\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    % A4 landscape = 2 x A5 portrait
    \makebox[\paperwidth][r]{%
      \includegraphics[angle = 90, height = \paperheight, valign = B]{example-image-a4}%
    }%
  }%
}%

\clearpage

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

The imported page is rotated and placed as-is on one A5 page, which only shows the top part of the A4 page. The bottom part runs off the page. For the bottom part, we place the image (rotated) in a box that is right-aligned to the page, thereby showing the bottom half.

Comment: Does it compensate for a small region in the inside margin where the printer cannot print?