# Printing A4 image in A5 document

Tags: graphics, formatting

I'm trying to print two-sided book with A5 pages. I'd like to insert A4 image into a spread of book. So it should be two pages with two halves of image and no inner margin. Can I do it without splitting original image but only using LaTeX code?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!  - See:  [Insert only half a pdf page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/410865/124842)